# Subsonic Compare Two Objects

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I would like to use [this](http://compareobjects.codeplex.com/) generic CompareObjects class but it seems that the Subsonic record objects don't implement IComparable.

```
User userFromDB = User.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "CmdrTallen");
User modifiedUser = new User();
TryUpdateModel(modifiedUser);
if(CompareOjbects<User>(userFromDB, modifiedUser) != 0)
{
    this.log("User was modified")
    //+ Add modified columns collection to log here
}
```

Am I re-inventing the wheel? Perhaps a easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using [this](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/don_peterson/archive/2006/07/08/1279.aspx) Generic Serializer to take both DB stored record (userFromDB) and modified user (modifiedUser). Serializing them to XML and then using [this](http://dotdiff.codeplex.com/) to create a diffgram. Exactly what I needed.

woot!

Answer (score 1):

By default the AR template overrides Equals() to compare primary keys instead of base Object comparison. You can change this by changing the ActiveRecord.tt file.